# Looking for Hakka old song about Tofu Seller

Tags: hakka

When I was a kid in Indonesia (about 30 years ago), I heard a cassette tape of a Hokkien/Hakka album about a Tofu Seller.

The album started with a man reciting a poem about when his 76-year-old father moved from mainland to Singapore and Malaya to study accounting, but after changing many jobs, at the end he became a tofu seller.

Where can I see a video or an mp3 or a translation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[客家阿伯酿豆腐](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XUOIhXl8xgw)

[歌詞](http://www.jianpu.cn/pu/25/255986.htm)

---

快速提升中文程度的方法：
1. 初級者多看中文文章。
2. 中級者多寫中文文章。
3. 高級者多用中文思考。
所以，除了初學者可能有困難外，建議大家多用中文問答。

Comment: Yes, this is it!

Comment: Then mark it as the correct answer!